# Grey out content editor ribbon button

Tags: content-editor

Is there any way to grey out the content editor archive button for all Sitecore items for every user
It should look like this

[image: Should look like this]

Comment: Are you asking about disabling the permissions so that users cannot use that button?

Comment: yes, but as per requirement, the button should be visible as shown in attached screenshot

Comment: You could deny the permission for a basic role for these items in the core database.

Comment: I think you want these buttons to be disabled but yet to be visible to content authors. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me

1. Create a Custom Command: Create a new class that inherits from
   **Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.Command** and implement the necessary
   logic for your button.

> ```
> using Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands;
>     public class MyCustomCommand : Command
>     {
>     public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
>     {
>         // Your custom logic here
>     }
>
>     public override CommandState QueryState(CommandContext context)
>     {
>         return CommandState.Disabled;
>     }
> }
> ```

2. Configure the Command in Sitecore: Create an XML configuration file in your Sitecore solution, e.g., MyCustomCommand.config, to define your command. Place this file in the **App_Config\Include** folder.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
> <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
>   <sitecore>
>     <commands>
>       <command name="mycustomcommand" type="YourNamespace.MyCustomCommand, YourAssembly" />
>     </commands>
>   </sitecore>
> </configuration>
> ```

3. Add command to your button

Answer (score 1):

To visually "grey out" a ribbon item, you can use custom CSS. You can apply CSS styles to make it appear disabled.

I checked the html element for the ribbon chunk you mentioned in Sitecore 9.3 and SC 10.3.1 and it seems that you can hide it using the CSS

```
.chunk#CE42470D6C6FC4F618BF7D87CC7A95659 {
      opacity: 0.5;
      pointer-events: none;
}
```

You can add this CSS in `{webroot}/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/default/Ribbon.css` or can create a custom CSS file for the same

Hope this helps!